# Android read and write to gallery

Tags: android

Is it possible to read and write to the gallery on Android?
I want to be able to get a list of all images in the gallery, and store those images onto a server. I also want to be able to download the images from the server and save them into the gallery. Is that possible?

I can't seem to find the API for doing this, so it would be great if you could point me in the right direction! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read from the gallery using the `ContentResolver.query()` method. For example:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query( Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, IMAGES_PROJECTION, null, null, Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER );
```

This will give you a `Cursor` to all photos in the database. `IMAGES_PROJECTION` is a `String[]` of columns you are interested in getting values from. These columns are listed in `Images.ImageColumns`.

To get the `Bitmap` for each image in the gallery, you need to get the `_ID` value for each row in the cursor, then call this:

```
Images.Media.getBitmap( getContentResolver(), Uri.withAppendedPath( Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Integer.toString( id ) ) );
```

To write to the content database, you can use:

```
Images.Media.insertImage( getContentResolver(), bitmap, title, description );
```

To insert a video is a bit more involved. If you need sample code for that, let me know and I can get that for you also.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I guess that is all i need right now. I will have a look at it! Again, thanks!